# create multiple categories in opencart

Tags: opencart

I developed this site using opencart (http://demob.atlastechng.com/edustuffs/) and this is my issue:

The side menu seems to pull information from the same top menu category. truth is i can decide to hide a new category from the top menu but not from the side menu.

Now, i'd love to create another list/category that will "Never" correspond to the top menu.

Eg the top menu may contain Home, Manipulatives, toys, books, e.tc
while the side menu will have a different menu..e.g Games, blogs, sale, other services, e.tc

How can i achieve this?

Please help

Comment: I think setting the sort order to -1 hides it from there, but not 100% and can't test at the minute

Comment: Hi Jay, the above does not solve the request, instead, it pushes the menu to the very top..

Answer (score 0):

Please Uncheck on Category Data Page "Top: Display in the top menu bar. Only works for the top parent categories." this will show the category on Side Menu but not in top menu.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.It is recommended to make use of comments regarding corrections or queries regarding the question,once you earn enough reputations.This answer might need little more explanation for fellow programmers to  understand how it works.

Comment: hello Sunil, thanks for the response. What I want to achieve is this: I want to create another category at the side menu with different menu at the top.. how do i achieve that?